# Inconsistent strptime accross different machines

Tags: python, strptime

So basically I have the a formula for getting the UNIX time, but I am getting 10800, and not 0, in my Ubuntu machine (in my mac it works just fine):

```
datetime.datetime(*time.strptime("01.01.1970","%d.%m.%Y")).timestamp()
>> 10800.0
```

I have seen a couple different questions, but none brought me any insight.

I think it is not a timezone issue, because:

```
datetime.datetime(time.strptime("01.01.1970.UTC", "%d.%m.%Y.%Z").timestamp()
>> 10800.0
```

Comment: Sounds like a time zone issue.

Comment: see edit, it is not

Comment: `datetime.datetime` doesn't actually take the arguments you're trying to pass it. `time.strptime`'s [output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time) doesn't actually match what `datetime.datetime` is [looking for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime). (You're *also* still probably having time zone issues, regardless of specifying `UTC` to `strptime`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **is** a timezone issue.  `time.strptime`, which relies on posix `strptime` returns a local time in all cases.

Please read the documentation of [`strptime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) carefully, you will note that while `%Z` is supported as a format character "fields are parsed, but *no field in `tm` is changed*"

Generally speaking, a posix implementation of `strptime` that does support `%Z` will only support the values of `UTC`, `GMT` or the systems `tzname` (available in python from `time.tzname`).  But *it will not alter the return value based upon them*.

Answer (score -2):

UNIX time is completely timezone dependent you may find clear answer here [en.wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)